# How we can create getter() an setter() method in typescript? When we can use these methods?

Tags: typescript, getter-setter

```
export class Element {
  private _class: string = null;

  get className() {
    return this._class;
  }

  set className(name) {
    this._class = `todd-${name}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: The example code seems to work.  Can you clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct, but for the full definition [see the typescript manual on Accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors).

Typically you would use these when:

- You want the `get` and `set` to have different modifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`)
- When you only want a getter or a setter, but not both. For example, when you want to allow anyone to read a value but not allow anyone to set it.
- When you want to execute some code whenever the value is get or set. For example, when you want to add logging.

Overal, `get` and `set` are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), in every situation they can be replaced by a function.